# React native iOS build issue An application bundle was not found at the provided path

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios

I am very new to react native. I have created a Hello World project and unable to run it on iOS. Every time when i run the project for iOS it throws the following error(s)

** BUILD FAILED **

The following build commands failed:
        CompileC /Users/usman/FunZoneAppsProjects/{ProjectName}/ios/build/Build/Intermediates/React.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/React.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/RCTShadowView+Internal.o Views/RCTShadowView+Internal.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)

Installing build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/{ProjectName}.app
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=2):
Failed to install the requested application
An application bundle was not found at the provided path.
Provide a valid path to the desired application bundle.
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist

Command failed: /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Print:CFBundleIdentifier build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/{ProjectName}.app/Info.plist
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist

Error: Command failed: /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Print:CFBundleIdentifier build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/{ProjectName}.app/Info.plist
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist

```
at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:621:11)
at Object.execFileSync (child_process.js:639:13)
at Promise.then (/Users/usman/FunZoneAppsProjects/{ProjectName}/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/runIOS/runIOS.js:208:5)
```

I have read many people resolved this issue with different fixes but none of them worked for me. What can be the issue? TIA

Answer (score 2):

I think this is connected with the new xcode version. Try opening your project in xcode. Go to File->Project Settings and choose Legacy build. Then try to rebuild your project.

Comment: This suggestion did not work for me. Deleted `ios/build` and `ios/DerivedData`, set Legacy Build, cleared caches, remove/reinstall `node_modules`. Still get `Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist`

Comment: nvm. needed to installs some cocoapods. wasn't aware they were added.

Comment: Legacy build is deprecated now. What is the solution in xcode 12??

Comment: Yes facing same issue with xcode-12 any fixes @DimpleShah

Comment: I have this issue as well after updating to Xcode 12

Comment: On Xcode 12, to fix this issue running on the command line; upgrade the [react-native CLI](https://github.com/react-native-community/cli#updating-the-cli)

Comment: `rm -rf node_modules; rm -f yarn.lock; yarn` then `yarn start` works.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me on mac OS Big Sur and Xcode 12 was,

1. Delete `package-lock.json` file.
2. Run `npm install` and `cd ios && pod install && cd ..`
3. Then opened the `.xcworkspace` file from Xcode and it worked.

Answer (score -1):

First of all you should be secure that `brew`, `node` and `watchman` are installed. After that, try to follow these steps.

1. Delete your actual project, close simulator, xcode and run on the path folder of your project  `watchman watch-del-all && rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-native-packager-cache-* && rm -rf $TMPDIR/metro-bundler-cache-* && rm -rf node_modules/ && npm cache clean`. Finally, close the command line
2. Create a folder in desktop named RNProjects.    Open the command line and run `cd Desktop/RNProjects`.
3. Run in the command line `react-native init myProjectName`. You can name the project as you want. You should change "myProjectName" for the desired project name.
4. After installation is completed (it takes a couple of minutes), be sure that in the command line you are in the path `RNProjects` and then run `cd myProjectName`. If you gave the project a different name, just replace "myProjectName" for the real project name.
5. Finally, just run `react-native run-ios`. Let me know if you want to test it in a real iDevice.

**EDIT 1**

If `brew, node or watchman` are not installed yet, follow this

1. For HOMEBREW follow this [link](https://brew.sh/). you should paste that at a Terminal prompt. `/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`
2. After that run `brew install node`
3. Then run `brew install watchman`
4. Then run `npm install -g react-native-cli`
5. Install Xcode command line tools [follow this link](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started#command-line-tools)

Comment: While running the command 'watchman watch-del-all && rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-native-packager-cache-* && rm -rf $TMPDIR/metro-bundler-cache-* && rm -rf node_modules/ && npm cache clean' It says watchman command not found.

Comment: Did you install watchman, brew and node? everything is on this link [Getting Started](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started)

Comment: Yes i installed everything except watchman, i ran the above mentioned command and all the instructions by you but did not work unfortunately. :/

Comment: No :/ Still struggling with the issue. :/

Comment: open the project folder. then open ios folder. then open the xcode project and run the simulator from xcode. make sure the signin profile it configured and the developer team.

Comment: In Signing section it says : Failed to create provisioning profile.
There are no devices registered in your account on the developer website. Plug in and select a device to have Xcode register it. While i want to run it in simulator.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184181/discussion-between-usman-iftakhar-and-helmer-barcos).